# Creating a new column based on conditions by groups in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
ID <- c(1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4)
Eval <- c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)
df <- data.frame(ID,Eval)
```

As long as there is one FALSE in `Eval` per `ID`, there should be a column, say x, indicating `TRUE`. How do I create this column?

The output should be:

```
ID  x 
 1  FALSE 
 2  TRUE 
 3  TRUE
 4  FALSE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `any` on the negated (`!`) 'Eval' after grouping by 'ID'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarise(x = any(!Eval))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
     ID x    
  <dbl> <lgl>
1     1 FALSE
2     2 TRUE 
3     3 TRUE 
4     4 FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative we could use `%in%` with `ifelse`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(x = ifelse(FALSE %in% Eval, TRUE, FALSE))
```

```
     ID x    
  <dbl> <lgl>
1     1 FALSE
2     2 TRUE 
3     3 TRUE 
4     4 FALSE
```